# Array passed as prop gets accepted as a string

Tags: reactjs, redux

Edit: Very stupid overlook on my time. Next time I'll read the documentation more slowly.

Passing an array as a prop, it gets accepted as a string with the same name.
For example if i'm passing `usersList = ['Name1', 'Name2', 'Name3']` to a child, the child only has access to `usersList` as a string, not its content.

Tried doing `const Table = ({usersList}) => {...}`, `const Table = (usersList)=>{...}`

The parent that inits the array:

```
import React from "react";
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import Table from "../presentational/Table.jsx";

const mapStateToProps = state => {
return { users: state.users };
};

const test = ["1", "4", "5"];

const ConnectedPeople = ({ users }) => {
return (
    <ul className="list-group list-group-flush">
        {console.log(test)}
        <Table usersList="{test}" />
    </ul>
);
};

const People = connect(mapStateToProps)(ConnectedPeople);

export default People;
```

The child accepting it

import React from "react";

```
const Table = usersList => {
return (
    <div>
        <pre>{Object.keys(usersList)}</pre>
    </div>
);
};

export default Table;
```

I would assume I can just do `usersList.map(...)`, but it comes as an object with every character of the string `usersList`. so the `Object.keys(usersList)` renders `usersList`

Comment: Dude you are passing string in the Table component , remove the double quotes from test.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is in the way you are passing the prop, which is in the form of a string. Instead you need to write

```
<Table usersList={test} />
```

Once you make the above change, you can simply access the array elements by mapping over the props like

```
this.props.usersList.map(...)
```

Comment: Oh my god, thank you. It has been quite a while without those stupid 5 hr endeavors for such a small overlook.

Answer (score 1):

problem:

```
<Table usersList="{test}" />
```

fix:

```
<Table usersList={test} />
```